# Download file phonegap sending post data

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, cordova

I have some client-side infos (a long associative array encoded with JSON) that I would like to send to the server with POST, to create an image based on those infos. The goal is to download that image using Phonegap primitives and saving it to the local storage.

Is there a way to do it?

Looking to the phonegap reference is there no way to send explicitely post data. Should I work with the parameter "header" (???) ?

Example:

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("http://some.server.com/create_my_image.php");

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    filePath,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    },
    false,
    {
        // HERE ADD SOME CODE TO SEND POST DATA?
        headers: {
            "???": "???"
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: But how are you going to save it in localStorage using above code?

Comment: I will use the other phonegap primitives later (FileWriter, ecc...), now I'm just trying to send a POST request passing by the FileTransfer class...

Comment: Its better u use AJAX to get the image as base64 data and save it into localStorage or indexedDB